# Building VideoConferencing Web app with my own SFU server in nodejs

Tags: node.js, networking, webrtc

I am building a SFU server for my web app but could not get a solution to how to get the peer media stream to my nodejs server. I know about mediasoup but I really want to handle the streams myself. My idea is to get the stream and clone it and pipe the clones to the other peers. Am I lacking some knowledge.

```
<no code>
<line1>
<line2>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.